# Changing font color in statusBar of Flex / Spark WindowedApplication Flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am trying to find out if it is possible to change the font color in the status bar of a WindowedApplication without having to make a custom skin. The problem is that I am using the graphite theme which is pretty dark and when I add text to the status bar it is a very dark gray color that is hardly readable. I should note that I am using flash builder 4.6 and Flex 4.6. I have tried changing the colors of the theme inside the design editor but none of these changed the font color.

The text will be generated with actionscript.  I noticed that there is also a statusBar variable that is an IVisualElement but I can't seem to find any documentation on this.This is how I am currently writing to the status bar.

```
this.status = "Testing";
```

Thank you for any information you can send my way.

Comment: Since WindowedApplication is only used for desktop apps; are you trying to change the OS Chrome?  Or some part of the Flex window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
this.statusText.text = "Testing";
this.statusText.setStyle("color",0xFF0000);
```